# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'

Tags: c++, clion

when i am tryign to enter poor name ( non numeric or alphabetic digit) i want to throw exeption. in the first time its working well but when i re enter to function again from the catch call and input again bad name i am getting this error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'"

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int numberOfWarrior = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numberOfthief = atoi(argv[2]);
    int numberOfnecromancer = atoi(argv[3]);
    int vecorSize = numberOfnecromancer + numberOfthief + numberOfWarrior;
    vector<Hero*> turnOfPlayer;
    //Enter Warrion Players
    if(numberOfWarrior>0) {
        try {
            enterWarrior(0, turnOfPlayer, numberOfWarrior,"warrior");
            }
        catch (int i) {
            cout << "Invalid name of user. You can only choose letters or numbers. Try again please." << endl;
            enterWarrior(i, turnOfPlayer, numberOfWarrior, "warrior");  // my program terminate when i enter to function from here
        }
    }

void enterWarrior(int index, vector<Hero*> v,int numOfWarrior, std::string Type)
{
    std::string nameOfwarrior;
    for(int i=index; i<numOfWarrior; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please insert " << Type << " number " << i+1 << " name:";
        cin >> nameOfwarrior;
        if(!digitCheck(nameOfwarrior))
            throw i;  // in the second time i get the error here 
        if(Type.compare("warrior")==0) {
            Warrior *warr = new Warrior(nameOfwarrior);
            v.push_back(warr);
        }
        if(Type.compare("thief")==0) {
            Thief *thief = new Thief(nameOfwarrior);
            v.push_back(thief);
        }
        if(Type.compare("necromancer")==0) {
            Necromancer *nec = new Necromancer(nameOfwarrior);
            v.push_back(nec);
        }
    }
}
```

i dont have any idea how can i solve it
thanks

Comment: Throwing in a `catch` won't allow the `catch` to catch again. It seems like you want to put your `try`/`catch` in a loop.

Comment: its exactly what i want , so how can i change it? my motivation is every time that i will enter wrong name i want to throw exception and try again

Comment: @DavidZaltsman look at my answer

Comment: Off-topic, but a user entering something bad is not worthy of an exception being thrown (it is not an *exceptional* event).  Unlike Java (or some other language) where exceptions are thrown all over the place for the smallest of issues, in C++, exceptions should be reserved for those things that should never occur, but for some reason, happen.  A person typing in something wrong happens many times, and is to be expected, thus "normal" error checking should be done, not an exception thrown.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree, _enterWarrior_ (in fact a better name is _enterWarriors_) can return -1 if all was ok or the wrong index in case of an error, index can be also in/out and the function return true/false etc. But I prefer _enterWarrior_ manages only one warrior and returns true/false to manage the index in the caller, seems more natural

Answer (score 0):

as it was said in a remark just use a loop, for instance :

```
if(numberOfWarrior>0) {
  int firstIndex = 0.

  for (;;) {
    try {
      enterWarrior(firstIndex, turnOfPlayer, numberOfWarrior,"warrior");
      // if we are here that means all is ok, go out of the loop
      break;
    }
    catch (int i) {
      cout << "Invalid name of user. You can only choose letters or numbers. Try again please." << endl;
      firstIndex = i;
    }
  }
}
```

Warning in  `void enterWarrior(int index, vector<Hero*> v,int numOfWarrior, std::string Type)` the vector is given by value, so *enterWarrior* modifies a **copy** of the vector, so change it by void enterWarrior(int index, vector & v,int numOfWarrior, std::string Type)`

`Type.compare("warrior")==0` etc are not very easy to read, you can replace them by `(Type == "warrior")` etc, we are in c++ not in Java

Some 'if' can be 'else if' to not compare for nothing when the previous 'if' was true. A final *else* seems missing also in case *Type* is not the expected, to indicate the problem whatever how

Comment: thanks but i loose my index and when i re enter to function i start again from 0 , i want to index keep so if the user made mistake he can try again so how can i keep the index i held before the throw?  *******************edit***************** now i see , thank you!

Comment: @DavidZaltsman In my  first proposal yes, I edited it, please reread it to also have more material